# Получаю ошибку и не могу понять почему?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
def process(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
        url = get_url(packet)
        print('[+] HTTP Request >>' + url)
```

получаю ошибку:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Answer (score 2, accepted):

через f-строку примерно то же самое

```py
print(f"[+] HTTP Request >>{url.decode()}")
```

Результат будет примерно такой

```
"[+] HTTP Request >>http://here-your-hostname.com"
```

Если не вызывать метод `decode()`, то ошибку вы не получите и по умолчанию будет вызван метод `str()`, но на выходе может быть неожиданный результат, который будет включать литеру `b''`. Что то такое:

```
"[+] HTTP Request >>b'http://here-your-hostname.com'"
```

Comment: Лучше явно указывать кодировку, т.к. она может отличаться в зависимости от ОС

Comment: По умолчанию `utf-8` же?

Comment: Вы правы, перепутал с `open` - подумал что в `decode` аналогичная логика :)

Comment: @Dmitry Спасибо, всё работает <3 Когда я использую MicrosofEdge всё работает прекрасно, ток HTTP страницы не грузит. Но теперь у меня возникает сложность, при использовании браузера Firefox мой скрипт перестает работать и выдаёт ошибку     in get_login_info
    if keyword in load:
    TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Если возникает другой вопрос, я вам советую создать новый. Здесь такой принцип -> конкретный вопрос - конкретный ответ

Answer (score 3):

Вы пытаетесь сложить два разных типа **byte** и **str**.
Исправить можно указанием кодировки выводе:

```
print('[+] HTTP Request >>' + url.decode('utf8'))
```

Либо выводом через str.format (что бывает полезно для логов):

```
print('[+] HTTP Request >>'.format(url))
```

Comment: `print('[+] HTTP Request >> {}'.format(url))` :)